# Angular-UI bootstrap popover directive component

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I developed a directive to maintain inline help for a widget from a dropdown bootstrap menu, but when I click help from the dropdown, the popover is currently bound to the element and cannot be separated, so it opens `absolute` from that position.

[image: What we have]

But the requirement would be if we click help in the dropdown we have show popover like below

[image: Actual Need]

I am not sure if it even possible, anyways I'll list down the efforts that I made.

- Angular-UI Bootstrap does not help, it does not possess any capabilities to programmatically trigger like bootstrap.
- However, In Angular-UI Bootstrap we can add triggers which was done by [Elijen](https://github.com/Elijen/angular-popover-toggle), but it would be divided into two components.

My issue would be to create a single directive housing both the trigger and the popover like the second image. I don't want to kill the sanity of bootstrap by overiding the CSS. I wanted to know either we could write a method to detect the position and move to the top of the widget or anything like that, since it would be a reusable component.

The reason why it's a single directive is, it would be packed into `webpack` and made a cross-cutter tool.

Comment: can you make a plunker or fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

The angular-ui-bootstrap popover listens to the popover-is-open attribute to support opening the popover programmatically.